# Не подключается доктрина к zf3

Tags: doctrine2, zend-framework-3

Пишет:

`( ! ) Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException: Service with name "doctrine.driver.orm_default" could not be created. Reason: Drivers must specify a class in /var/www/projects/library2/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php on line 765`

В файл modules.config.php добавил:

    `'DoctrineModule',
    'DoctrineORMModule',`

Содержимое doctrine.global.php:

```
<?php
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOPgSql\Driver;    

return [
    'doctrine' => [
        'connection' => [
            'orm_default' => [
                'driverClass' => Driver::class,
                'params' => [
                    'host' => 'localhost',
                    'port' => '5432',
                    'user' => 'production',
                    'password' => 'production',
                    'dbname' => 'library',
                ]
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установка Doctrine, через composer

```
composer require doctrine/doctrine-orm-module
composer require doctrine/doctrine-module
```

Далее в файл modules.config.php добавить **DoctrineModule**, **DoctrineORMModule**

```
/**
 * List of enabled modules for this application.
 *
 * This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
 */
return [

    // ....
    'DoctrineModule',
    'DoctrineORMModule',
    // .....
];
```

Мой рабочий конфиг doctrine.global.php.

```
<?php
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver as PDOMySqlDriver;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver;

return [
    'doctrine' => [
        'connection' => [
            // настройка соединения с базой данных MySQL
            'orm_default' => [
                'driverClass' => PDOMySqlDriver::class,
                'params' => [
                    'host' => 'localhost',
                    'port' => '3306',
                    'user' => '[]',
                    'password' => '[]',
                    'dbname' => '[]',
                    'charset' => 'utf8',
                    'driverOptions' => [
                        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES "UTF8"',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],

        'driver' => [
            'Doctrine_driver' => [
                'class' => AnnotationDriver::class,
                'cache' => 'array',
                'paths' => [
                    __DIR__ . '/../../module/Application/src/Entity',
                ],
            ],
            'orm_default' => [
                'drivers' => [
                    'Application\Entity' => 'Doctrine_driver',
                ],
            ],
        ],

    ],
];
```

Надеюсь вам это поможет